# How to set {{#each }} iterate value from helper

Tags: handlebars.js, helper

Usually for a `{{#each}}` block, we can set the *value* directly in it like: `{{#each users}}`:

```
user: [
    {name: 'foo'},
    {name: 'bar'}
]
```

What I need to do is do be able to set the `{{#each}}` iteration value from a helper.

I have tried with this `helper`:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('myHelper', function () {
  return new Handlebars.SafeString('users');
});

## also tested with:
Handlebars.registerHelper('myHelper', function () {
  return 'users';
});
```

and in my view:

```
{{#each (myHelper)}} # and {{#each myHelper}}
  <p>{{name}}</p>
{{/each}}
```

But nothing get shown.

I appreciate if anyone can give me some pointers. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a built-in function called `lookup` in order to achieve what you are trying to achieve.

Try:

```
{{#each (lookup . (myHelper))}}
   {{name}}
{{/each}}
```